# Calling EDB Stored procedure(which is having output parameter) using EDB*plus from remote server

Tags: enterprisedb

EDB plus is being used for the purpose of calling Enterprise Database procedure (EDB SPL), the return value of the procedure is to be captured in a shell variable. Need syntax and details for the same. The database is on a remote machine.

I am able to call the EDB SPL (stored procedure) without mentioning it's output parameter using `EDB * Plus` from remote server. But not able to capture its output parameter's values into shell local variables.

```
--shell script code(OS is Linux, EDB version 11.3.10)
Proc_result=`edbplus -S $DB_USER/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_SCHEMA 2>>EDB_ERROR_FILE <<END_OF_SQL
set feedback off
set pages 0
set flush off
set feedback on
exec schema1.procedure_1(input_param1, input_param2, input_param3);
exit;
END_OF_SQL`

--EDB procedure signature
schema1.procedure_1(input_param1 varchar2, 
                    input_param2 number,
            input_param3 varchar2,
                    output_param1 varchar2,
            output_param2 number);
```

I want to get value of "output_param1" and "output_param2" in the shell variable "Proc_result"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use `CALL` instead of `EXEC`?

```
[root@ep11 bin]# DB_USER=enterprisedb
[root@ep11 bin]# DB_PASSWORD=abc123
[root@ep11 bin]# DB_SCHEMA="127.0.0.1:5432/edb"
[root@ep11 bin]# Proc_result=`edbplus -S $DB_USER/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_SCHEMA 2>>EDB_ERROR_FILE <<END_OF_SQL
> set feedback off
> set pages 0
> set flush off
> set feedback on
> exec schema1.procedure_1('foo',1,'bar');
> exit;
> END_OF_SQL`
[root@ep11 bin]# echo $Proc_result;
EDB-SPL Procedure successfully completed.
[root@ep11 bin]# Proc_result=`edbplus -S $DB_USER/$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_SCHEMA 2>>EDB_ERROR_FILE <<END_OF_SQL
set feedback off
set pages 0
set flush off
set feedback on
call schema1.procedure_1('foo',1,'bar');
exit;
END_OF_SQL`
[root@ep11 bin]# echo $Proc_result;
02c6e1417aae6f6719a772fe7ea2cfac 1 CALL completed.
[root@ep11 bin]# psql -c "call schema1.procedure_1('foo',1,'bar')"
          output_param1           | output_param2 
----------------------------------+---------------
 02c6e1417aae6f6719a772fe7ea2cfac |             1
(1 row)
```